# Value from one table as DateAdd interval in INSERT statement to another table

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, insert

I need to use a value from one table as a DateAdd interval in an INSERT statement to a second table

offices:

```
officeID | office | deadline
```

orders:

```
orderID | officeID | DateReceived | DateDue
```

Here's what I've been trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO orders(officeID, DateReceived, DateDue)
    VALUES (1, #2018-06-14#, DateAdd("d", (SELECT deadline FROM offices WHERE officeID = 1), "2018-06-14"))
```

Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO orders (officeID, DateReceived, DateDue)
   SELECT 1, #2018-06-14#, DateAdd("d", deadline, "2018-06-14")
   FROM offices
   WHERE officeID = 1;
```

That said, I wonder if you just want `update`:

```
update orders
    set datedue = (select DateAdd("d", deadline, "2018-06-14")
                   from offices
                   where orders.officeID = offices.officeID
                  )
    where officeID = 1;
```

Comment: Insert...Select - exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!